# How to put text from editbox into a website login fields

Tags: android, webview, editbox

hey guys what I am trying to do is have two edit boxes for a user to sign into a website.  I do not want to use a webview.  my question is how can i get the inputted values from the editbox and put it in as their sign in info (i.e username and password) and return the result if it was successful or not?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just wrote an app that did this exact thing. My first question is what technology are you using on the web side?  For me it was asp.NET. You can use either a GET or POST method to send your user credentials and get your result. I suggest using POST since the information is sensitive and POST is better for that type of information. Here is the code.

ASPX Code:

```
string User = Request.Form["u"];
string Pass = Request.Form["p"];
Response.Write(ValidateUser(u, p));
//I won't show you the validation code for security reasons.  But I think you get the idea.
```

ANDROID CODE:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        //Gets your login button and sets onClickListener
        Button btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    //Get your TextBox from the layout
                    EditText etUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUser);
                    EditText etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPass);

                    //Client to make the request to your web page
                    DefaultHttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    //This is where you put the information you're sending.
                    HttpPost postUserCredentials = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.LoginAddress));
                    HttpEntity postParameters = new StringEntity("u=" + etUserName.getText() + "&p=" + etPassword.getText());

                    postUserCredentials.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    postUserCredentials.setEntity(postParameters);

                    HttpResponse postResponse = myClient.execute(postUserCredentials);
                    HttpEntity postResponseEntity = postResponse.getEntity();

                    String result = EntityUtils.toString(postResponseEntity);

                    if (result.equals("1")) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Login Succeeded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

login.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvUser" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Username:" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/etUser" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPass" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Password:" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/etPass" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:password="true" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Login" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great, I'm glad to have helped.  If this answer is what you were looking for make sure you "accept" it by clicking the Green check mark.  It will encourage others to answer your future questions.